# Cannot get grunt to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I am having some trouble with grunt. I am using a small software piece writing by us to publish and make an email, however when I run the command to create the emails a grunt error happens and I have tried fixing it but I cannot, it works on the rest of my teams computer but it does not work on mine. Could someone please help?
   `Running "imagemin:dynamic" (imagemin) task
   Fatal error: Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined`
Thank you for the help

These are other errors I get:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v4.2.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! emails@1.0.0 dev: `grunt default`
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the emails@1.0.0 dev script 'grunt default'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the emails package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     grunt default
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs emails
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls emails
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/iPatriot/projects/aliada/emails/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: have you ran `npm install` ?

Comment: I was confused, now I get it. Lol.

Comment: The point of failure looks to be emails@1.0.0 dev, so start there, Grunt itself looks to be working ok.

Comment: I did run `npm install`